# Question about rendering .tiff image in HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, xhtml, tiff

In my html page, I created an  tag to render some of my .tif format images.

Since .tif images can not be rendered directly in "src" attribute of the  tag, so I created the following code to render it:

```
  <object width="200" height="200" type="image/tiff" data="Test.tif">
          <param name="src" value="Test.tif"/>
          <param name="negative" value="yes"/>
  </object>
```

Everything worked perfectly :) in both Chrome and Firefox, but the image is not rendering in IE. Wonder if any expert could offer some help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tif` is not a standard format for the web (though the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/) doesn't define a standard list) and it won't be displayed in all browsers.

It looks like it only has support for IE and Safari.

[Browser Image Support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)

Comment: thank you for your help, now I choose to use an <iframe> to enclose the tiff image, this works in IE, Chrome and FireFox, though renders not very nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a different file format, e.g. by screen capturing it using the PrtScrn button, then cropping it on Paint and saving it as a jpg/png/etc. file that every browser can display. If not, then somehow you will have to tell people to modify their registry because there is a registry that prevents .tif files by being rendered. Try looking at this:

http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1182/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PHP and ImageMagick to convert the tiff images to png or jpeg on the fly. That way they will render nicely and work in all browsers.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php